# Unexpected symbol void in unity

Tags: visual-studio

The following error occurs when I use void.

> "Unexpected symbol void, expecting class, delegate, enum, interface, partial, or struct"

The error is for last two voids.

Here are the screenshots with script and error: 
[image]

This is my code producing the error.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PauseMenu : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static bool GameisPaused = false;

    public GameObject pauseMenuUI;
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
        {
            if (GamseIsPaused)
            {
                Resume();
            }
            else
            {
                Pause();
            }
        }
    }
}

void Resume()
{

    pauseMenuUI.SetActive(false);
    Time.timeScale = 1f;
    GameisPaused = false;
}

void Pause()
    {
        pauseMenuUI.SetActive(true);
        Time.timeScale = 0f;
        GameisPaused = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a '}' too many after your Update Function / before Resume. Remove it!

[image]